# Can silicone oil evaporate at an appreciable rate at low pressures?

Tags: pressure, evaporation

Under normal conditions of ambient temperature and pressure, evaporation of silicone oils is so slow that it can be neglected, because the vapour pressure of the oil is typically of the order of hundreds of pascals.

Can the evaporation rate be appreciably increased by decreasing the pressure?  My first thought was that as long as we do not drop below a pressure which is of the order of thousands of pascals, the evaporation rate of the oil should still be negligible, but now I am not sure.

Comment: Probably belongs here: https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/ Evaporating silicone oil, even at strongly reduced pressure, may be nigh impossible, IMO...

Comment: @Gert - those with ultra-high vacuum experience would disagree!

Comment: I guess the question is what would happen if you introduced silicone oil into a sealed evacuated container.  Wouldn't it evaporate?

Comment: @JonCuster Maybe but I'm not talking about ultra-high vacuum, of course1 :-)

Comment: I still think that as long as you don't go to ultra-high vacuum, the evaporation of the oil should not be significant.